# Writing azure consumption Logic app traces to App Insights

Tags: azure-logic-apps

Can I send traces of steps in my consumption logic app workflow to any application insight? Is there an out of box provision for the same?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no out of box connector available to trace logs in Application Insights for Consumption Logic App.

There are two options available

1. Use Tracked Properties to send custom fields that needs to be tracked to Log Analytics Workspace.
   [Check this](https://www.tech-findings.com/2019/10/getting-started-with-logic-apps-what-happened-to-request.html)
2. Invoke Azure Function from Logic App to log into App Insights.

or you can use Standard LA which is recommended for enterprise production scenarios

Answer (score 0):

*While you are linking application insight to your logic app which ever application insight you provide in logic only those traces will be sent to email.*

[image]

*You can go through the [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/automate-with-logic-apps) for further information.*